# Match and tag the string of one column to the substring of another column

Tags: python, pandas, automation, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I need Python code that takes the strings in column x,y and matches these substrings in column Z and replace the substrings with a tagged version of the substrings as seen below

**Input: Untagged substrings**

```
    Target  Effect  Sentence
0   "hsp9   "insulin sensitivity" "treatment of fhrs with doxycycline attenuated the decrease in enos and hsp90 expression but did not improve insulin sensitivity."
1   "hsp90"    "apoptosis"   "radicicol, an inhibitor of hsp90, enhances trail-induced apoptosis in human epithelial ovarian carcinoma cells by promoting activation of apoptosis-related proteins."
```

**Output: Tagged Substrings**

```
    Target  Effect  Sentence
0   "hsp90"    "insulin sensitivity"   "treatment of fhrs with doxycycline attenuated the decrease in enos and <e1>hsp90</e1> expression but did not improve <e2>insulin sensitivity</e2>."
1   "hsp90"    "apoptosis"    "radicicol, an inhibitor of <e1>hsp90</e1>, enhances trail-induced apoptosis in human epithelial ovarian carcinoma cells by promoting activation of <e2>apoptosis</e2>-related proteins."
```

I would like to do this using pandas and dataframes.
Use the example above how would I go about completing such a task.

Comment: Images are highly [`discouraged`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), instead include sample input along with expected output that can be copy pasted along with code snippet of what you have tried.

Comment: I have improved the format of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `apply()` and treating each of the columns as a *reg expr* match for s substitution it's straight forward.

```
import re
data = '''    Target  Effect  Sentence
0   hsp90   insulin sensitivity   "treatment of fhrs with doxycycline attenuated the decrease in enos and hsp90 expression but did not improve insulin sensitivity."
1   hsp90    apoptosis   "radicicol, an inhibitor of hsp90, enhances trail-induced apoptosis in human epithelial ovarian carcinoma cells by promoting activation of apoptosis-related proteins."'''
a = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in [re.sub("([0-9]+[ ])*(.*)", r"\2", l) for l in data.split("\n")]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])

df["Sentence"] = df.apply(lambda r: re.sub(f"({r['Effect']})", r"<e2>\1</e2>", 
                          re.sub(f"({r['Target']})", r"<e1>\1</e1>", r["Sentence"])), axis=1)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
Target               Effect                                                                                                                                                                                            Sentence
 hsp90  insulin sensitivity                                                "treatment of fhrs with doxycycline attenuated the decrease in enos and <e1>hsp90</e1> expression but did not improve <e2>insulin sensitivity</e2>."
 hsp90            apoptosis  "radicicol, an inhibitor of <e1>hsp90</e1>, enhances trail-induced <e2>apoptosis</e2> in human epithelial ovarian carcinoma cells by promoting activation of <e2>apoptosis</e2>-related proteins."
```